# Create an image map from layers

Tags: adobe-photoshop, slices

I have an image of the USA. I'm currently cutting it up into layers, one state per layer. I'd like to convert this into an image map, with all the glorious html around that.

- Is there a simple method to do create this form of polygonal
  image-map?
- If not a simple method, what would be the more complex method within
  photoshop?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question which was about polygonal image maps. As far as I can see in Photoshop you can only do square blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to create image maps from layers is to click on each layer and then select `Layer` ⇒ `New Layer Based Slice` from the menus at the top of the screen.  Once you have created a slice, you can use the `Slice Select Tool` to select and modify the slice (adding things like URL, target window, etc.)

Answer (score -2):

GIMP, the free photoshop equivalent has a great "filter" that lets you turn selections of any shape in to image maps generating the code on the fly.  Well worth the free cost.